# Infinite redirect when using mod_proxy_ajp ?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm trying to configure access from the root context of port 80 to redirect to my tomcat app. My config is set up like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/ajp.error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/ajp.log combined

   <Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>

   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/testApp
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/testApp
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this the correct way to do this ? It currently results in an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Are you sure it is the ProxyPass that is causing the redirect? What does your Tomcat configuration look like (including any <transport-guarantee> for the webapp you are trying to reach)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ProxyPassReverse configuration is wrong. You want:

```
   ProxyPass        / ajp://localhost:8009/testApp
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/testApp
```

The ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines should have identical arguments.

Since you are changing the application path you may run into all sorts of additional issues including but not limited to:

- cookies having the wrong path
- embedded links using the wrong path
- some libraries that place paths in custom HTTP headers using the wrong paths

Generally, life is a lot easier if you rename testApp to ROOT.

Comment: Yeah ok I deployed as root and it works this way. Just a note to say the proxy path configuration correction was incorrect, http protocol needs to be used for the reverse when using ajp

Comment: No it wasn't. If you had to have mis-matched ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse lines to get things to work, something else in your setup is badly broken.

Comment: When I configure it both ways with ajp I get a proxy error. My understanding of the area isn't complete so maybe i'm wrong. I would guess that ajp passing back out can't be used ??